# javascript on click show/hide content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, message

I'm trying to develop a private message system using php/mysql.

I've got a database set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `messageID` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msgTo` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `msgFrom` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sendTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`messageID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I list the messages sent to a specific username as follows:

```
<?php               
 $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msgTo = '$username'"; // I know SELECT * should be avoided but there's not many columns here anyway
    $result = mysql_query($query);              
    while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   ?>         
        <ul class='lbe_list'>
        <li>                    
            <a href=''>             
            <?php
            echo "From: ".$messages['msgFrom']."</a>&nbsp;Subject: ".$messages['subject'];?>
    </li></a></ul>  
    <?php 
}
```

Which lists the sender and the subject of the message.

**However, I want to be able to click the username and subject here, and use JavaScript to expand the window so it will list the message itself below. Like the following:**

```
<a href=''>             
<?php
    echo "From: ".$messages['msgFrom']."</a>&nbsp;Subject: ".$messages['subject'];?>
    </li></a></ul>
<?php 
// on click expand/hide $messages['message'];
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This hurts my eyes. Please google to Accordion plugin, you are reinventing the wheel in a very ugly way.

Comment: There are some beautiful plugin`s for accordion at codrops, http://tympanus.net/codrops/tag/accordion/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php               
 $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msgTo = '$username'"; // I know SELECT * should be avoided but there's not many columns here anyway
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $m_no=0;
    while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $m_no++;
?>         
        <ul class='lbe_list'>
        <li>                    
            <a href=''>             
            <?php
                echo "<span id='$m_no' onclick=\"document.getElementById('body_".$m_no."').style.display=(document.getElementById('body_".$m_no."').style.display=='none'? 'block': 'none')\">"."From: ".$messages['msgFrom']."</span></a>&nbsp;Subject: ".$messages['subject'];
                echo "<div id='body_".$m_no."' style=\"display:none; border:2px solid green;\">".htmlspecialchars($messages['message'])."</div>";
            ?>
    </li></a></ul>  
<?php 
    }
?>
```

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/brKrZ/)**

Comment: When I click on the link using this code, the message itself will appear for only a fraction of a second. Could you please tell me how to fix it, because this seems to be exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This code is to make a toggle. With one click the message will appear and the 2nd click will collapse it. That's all. But what you say is really unexpected. Please highlight the problem clearly.

Comment: Only "From: myusername" is part of the link. If I click that, the message itself flashes on screen for a fraction of a second. If I click on the "Subject: messageSubject" below, it expands the message as intended. So I need to set the on click event to the link part "From: myusername" instead of the "Subject: someSubject"

Comment: Done. Check it. I have set the link operation on the `from:username` section.

Answer (score 0):

for one, this is not valid html structure

```
<ul class='lbe_list'>
 - <li>                    
 - - <a href=''>
 - - </a>
 - </li>
 - </a>
</ul>
```

The basic idea to solve this problem, is to name the element that contains whatever you want to show with a id="" and hiding it with style="display:none", and then attach a onclick handler to that which should display it.
In its most basic form:

```
<ul class='lbe_list'>
<?php while($messages = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>         
    <li>                    
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('message-<?php echo $messages['messageID']; ?>').style.display='block'">
        <?php echo "From: ".$messages['msgFrom']."&nbsp;Subject: ".$messages['subject'];?>
    </a> 
    </li>
    <li id="message-<?php echo $messages['messageID']; ?>" style="display:none">
        <?php echo $messages['message']; ?> 
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: messageID In hes database schema is the primary key, by definition it CANNOT be the same for two messages, ergo, the message id in the html will never be the same unless he decides to use the "message-" prefix for something else or print the message twice with the same prefix

Comment: long id strings? so thats why you went ahead and voted me down. Great. If you really want to, you can shorten it to msg, or m if you like. doesnt really matter. When providing an example for someone to learn from i prefer to make it readable above all else

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use javascript, preferably jQuery, to do that. Take a look at

http://api.jquery.com/show/

and

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

or

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

to see the proper usage

Comment: Are you kidding? Is it a standard answer at all??? If you were to give just an hint, you should have made a comment but not an answer.